# Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: php, mysql

When this script is being runned:

```
<?php
      $username = "root";
      $host = "localhost";
      $pass = "mypass";
      $db = "api";
      $key = $_GET['key'];
      mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$pass")or die("cannot connect"); 
      mysql_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select DB");
      $key = stripslashes($key);
      $key = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE key='. $key .'");
      if (!$result) { // add this check.
         die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
      }else{
         echo "done";
      }
?>
```

It shows me the error:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys WHERE key='. aL6MP .'' at line 1

Comment: SELECT * FROM `keys` WHERE `key`='$key'

Comment: Has any of the answers helped you so far?

Comment: both `keys` and `key` are reserved

Answer (score 0):

You should not use double quotes when passing the variables in your connection:

```
  mysql_connect($host, $username, $pass) or die ("Could not connect to Server");
```

Remove the spaces between `'$key'` and you don't have to concatenate as well.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE key='$key'");
```

or make it even simple:

```
$que = "SELECT * FROM keys WHERE key='$key'";
$result = mysql_query($que);
```

> Shift from depricated mysql_* functions to either mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the single and double quotes in your sql.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE key='". $key ."'; ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed some quotes. Change you query to this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE key='".$key ."'");
```

Or don't use concatenation hence you are using double quotes

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE key='$key'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following lines:

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$pass")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select DB");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE key='. $key .'");
```

To:

```
// No need to quote variables
mysql_connect($host, $username, $pass) or die("cannot connect");
// No need to quote variable 
mysql_select_db($db) or die("cannot select DB");
// No need to concatonate variable, add "``" backticks around table and column names to prevent SQL reserved word error.
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `keys` WHERE `key` = '$key'");
```

> Also note that `mysql_*` is depracted and will be removed go with `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `mysqli` instead.

and what you've done wrong is

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE key='. $key .'");
```

you're not opening and closing `quotes` and `concatenation(dots)` properly.
So you can do either of following.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE key='$key'");
```

OR

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE key='". $key ."'");
```

it totally upto you, both will yield the same results.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE key='. $key .'");` with `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE key='$key");`

OR

Replace `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE key='. $key .'");` with `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE key='". $key ."'");`